# Как получить ссылку ajax запроса на python

Tags: python, ajax, парсер, request, xhr

Пишу парсер торговой площадки(тп) стим, а точнее конкретных вещей. Всё работает, поскольку я беру Request URL из вкладки Network, на примере этой страницы тп (https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Music%20Kit%20%7C%20Knock2%2C%20dashstar%2A) её ссылка запроса будет (https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=BY&language=russian&currency=1&item_nameid=176328044&two_factor=0),откуда получаем json ответ. Т.к. Request URL всех предметов идентична и отличается только переменной nameid, которая лежит в Query String Parameters всех запросов на данной странице, а достать её я не знаю как. Возможно ли не в ручную доставать Request URL, а имея только ссылку предмета на тп получать её? Или можно как-то доставать значение nameid?, тогда ссылка запроса и не нужна, поскольку она будет генерироваться 'начало_строки + nameid + конец'
з.ы. решение ищу без использования селениум, или это невозможно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Selenium в помощь

Comment: @МихаилРебров Забыл упомянуть. что решение ищу без использования селениум, или это невозможно?

Comment: нажмите на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1445465/edit)  вопросом и напишите об этом в вопросе.

Comment: относительно невозможности ничего пока сказать не могу

Comment: "Или можно как-то доставать значение nameid?" В исходниках(HTML) смотрите